# Accessing a Subprocess started by another script

Tags: python, docker, subprocess

I have Script 1(Container Entrypoint). Script 1 starts a subprocess using Popen. It's "Waits" this process to recieve live input commands from the console and keep the server running.

```
    game_server = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*run_command, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    async for startup_out_line in game_server.stdout:
        console_print(startup_out_line.decode())
        if server_start_string in startup_out_line.decode('utf-8', 'replace'):
            print("Server Started")
            break

    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        in_task = tg.create_task(running_server_inpipe(game_server))
        out_task = tg.create_task(running_server_outpipe(game_server))
        err_task = tg.create_task(running_server_errpipe(game_server))
        retcode = await game_server.wait()
        if retcode == 0:
            print("Server exited normally")
        else:
            print(f"Error: server exited with code {retcode}")
        in_task.cancel()
        out_task.cancel()
        err_task.cancel()
        
    sys.exit(0 if retcode == 0 else 1)

async def running_server_inpipe(game_server: asyncio.subprocess.Process):
    while True:
        line = await aioconsole.ainput("Enter Command: ")
        game_server.stdin.write(line.encode('utf-8') + b"\n")
        await game_server.stdin.drain()
        console_print("INPIPE - Command Sent: " + line)

async def running_server_outpipe(game_server: asyncio.subprocess.Process):
    async for out_line in game_server.stdout:
        console_print("OUTPIPE - Server Says: " + out_line.decode('utf-8', 'replace'))

async def running_server_errpipe(game_server: asyncio.subprocess.Process):
    async for err_line in game_server.stderr:
        console_print("ERRORPIPE - Server Error: " + err_line.decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
```

I then have Script 2(API) which receives commands from an external source, and tries to access the subprocess started by Script 1, and write a command to it's stdin.

```
@API1.route('/quit', methods=['POST'])
def receive_quit_data():
    data = request.get_json()
    try:
        server = data['server']
    except KeyError:
        return jsonify({'status': 'No Server Provided'})
    engage_container = ["docker", "attach", f"{server}"]
    container_process = subprocess.Popen(engage_container, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, text=True)
    container_process.communicate(input="quit\n")
    container_process.wait()
    if container_process.return_code == 0:
        return jsonify({'status': 'Command Sent'})
    return jsonify({'status': 'Command Failed'})
```

Although I'm getting a 200code back from the API. The subprocess doesn't response to these commands at all. If I log into the terminal directly and write:

```
docker attach <SERVERNAME>
```

then

```
save\n
```

it responds as expected and so I know Script 1 is working correctly!
I think this might be something to do with PTY (terminal) but not sure...

Any help/pointers would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Trying to use file descriptors can be tricky here.  Can you set up some sort of network listener here, either driving the first process with a socket listener or (probably better) sending HTTP requests instead of line-oriented text input?

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze - I have gone with aiohttp for a small loopback server!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipes to communicate with subprocess.
In below example "cat" is started and everything you write in the terminal is send to subprocess stdin. Data from subprocess is then fetched and printed in the terminal:

```py
import subprocess
import select
import sys, os
import fcntl

process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["cat"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=False,
    bufsize=0,
    pipesize=0
)
fcntl.fcntl(process.stdout, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)

while process.poll() is None:
    readable, _, _ = select.select([process.stdout, sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
    while readable:
        p = readable.pop()
        if p == process.stdout:  # read from process stdin pipe
            sys.stdout.write(process.stdout.read().decode())
            sys.stdout.flush()
        elif p == sys.stdin:
            # read from pythons app stdin. Send it to process as command
            d = sys.stdin.readline().encode()
            process.stdin.write(d)  # send to the process
```

Comment: Not sure if you read the Question here Mike? Already using that in a more complicated solution with aioconsole. The problem is the first subprocess is out of scope of the 2nd script.